# Rider throws issues on runing code cover tests

Tags: code-coverage, rider

i installed the version 2023.1.3 of rider and used dotnet version 7.0.203.
All works fine expect the execution of the Cover tests.

If i run the cover tests the rider throws the following errors:
Test has not run

Last runner error: Test runner agent exited unexpectedly Process

> C:\Users\username.dotnet\dotnet.exe:1996 exited with code
> '-2147450730': Not available
>
> --- EXCEPTION #1/3 [UnknownExitCodeException] Message =    Process C:\Users\username.dotnet\dotnet.exe:1996 exited with code
> '-2147450730':   Not available
>
> ExceptionPath = Root.InnerException.InnerException ClassName =
> JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Common.Exceptions.UnknownExitCodeException
> HResult = COR_E_EXCEPTION=80131500
>
> --- Outer ---
>
> --- EXCEPTION #2/3 [ProcessExitedUnexpectedlyException] Message = “Test runner agent exited unexpectedly” ExceptionPath =
> Root.InnerException ClassName =
> JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Common.Exceptions.ProcessExitedUnexpectedlyException
> InnerException = “Exception #1 at Root.InnerException.InnerException”
> HResult = COR_E_EXCEPTION=80131500 Source =
> JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework StackTraceString =    at
> JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.Activation.TestRunnerAgent.AnalyseExitCode(IPreparedProcess
> process) in AnalyseExitCode.il:line IL_00BD mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.Activation.TemporaryTestRunnerAgentInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__3()
> in TemporaryTestRunnerAgentInvoker.il:line IL_0000 mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Common.Extensions.TaskExtensions.ThrowIf[TResult,TException](Task1
> task, WaitHandle waitHandle, Func1 exceptionFactory) in
> ThrowIf.il:line IL_00F6 mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Common.Extensions.TaskExtensions.CancelIf[TResult](Task1
> task, CancellationToken ct) in CancelIf.il:line IL_0176 mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.Activation.TemporaryTestRunnerAgentInvoker.StartTestRunnerAgent(ITestRunnerContext
> ctx, CancellationToken ct) in StartTestRunnerAgent.il:line IL_01A4
> mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.dotCover.Ide.Core.UnitTesting.Model.PreloadedTestRunners.PreloadedTestRunnerAgentPool.StartTestRunnerAgentFromNewThread(ITestRunnerContext
> context, CancellationToken ct) in
> StartTestRunnerAgentFromNewThread.il:line IL_00EC mvid 168E
> at JetBrains.dotCover.Ide.Core.UnitTesting.Model.PreloadedTestRunners.PreloadedTestRunnerAgentPool.Allocate(ITestRunnerContext
> context, CancellationToken ct) in Allocate.il:line IL_03CA mvid 168E
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.TestRunnerAgentManager.GetExecutionAgent(ITestRunnerExecutionContext
> context, CancellationToken ct) in GetExecutionAgent.il:line IL_0083
> mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.TestRunnerRunStrategy.StartTestRunner(IUnitTestRun
> run, ITestRunnerAdditionalStartupOptions environmentSpecifier,
> CancellationToken cancelCt, CancellationToken abortCt) in
> StartTestRunner.il:line IL_008F mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.TestRunnerRunStrategy.Run(IUnitTestRun
> run) in Run.il:line IL_013D mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.Launch.UnitTestRun.StartCore(CancellationToken
> onCancel, CancellationToken onAbort) in StartCore.il:line IL_01E7 mvid
> 4421 or StartCore.il:line IL_03B3 mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.Launch.UnitTestRun.<>c.b__37_0(ExceptionDispatchInfo
> e) in UnitTestRun.il:line IL_0000 mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.Util.Special.GeneralUtil.WithNotNull[T](T item, Action1 F) in WithNotNull.il:line IL_0016 mvid 3127
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.Launch.UnitTestRun.StartCore(CancellationToken
> onCancel, CancellationToken onAbort) in StartCore.il:line IL_01E7 mvid
> 4421 or StartCore.il:line IL_03B3 mvid 4421
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.Launch.UnitTestRun.Start(CancellationToken
> onCancel, CancellationToken onAbort) in Start.il:line IL_016D mvid
> 4421
>
> --- Outer ---
>
> --- EXCEPTION #3/3 [LoggerException] Message = “Test runner agent exited unexpectedly” ExceptionPath = Root ClassName =
> JetBrains.Util.LoggerException InnerException = “Exception #2 at
> Root.InnerException” HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
> StackTraceString =    at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.LogException(ILogger
> this, LoggingLevel level, Exception exception, ExceptionOrigin
> exceptionOrigin, String comment) in LogException.il:line IL_002E mvid
> 3127
> at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.Error(ILogger this, Exception exception, ExceptionOrigin origin, String comment) in Error.il:line
> IL_0000 mvid 3127
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.Launch.UnitTestRun.Start(CancellationToken
> onCancel, CancellationToken onAbort) in Start.il:line IL_016D mvid
> 4421
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object
> s) in ExecutionContextCallback.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in
> RunInternal.il:line IL_0040 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread
> threadPoolThread) in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or
> MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext()
> in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid
> 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox
> box, Boolean allowInlining) in RunOrScheduleAction.il:line IL_003B
> mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject) in RunContinuations.il:line IL_0065 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean userDelegateExecute) in FinishSlow.il:line IL_0003 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject) in TrySetException.il:line IL_0022 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetException(Exception
> exception, Task1& taskField) in SetException.il:line IL_0025 mvid 2BEF
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.Launch.UnitTestRun.StartCore(CancellationToken
> onCancel, CancellationToken onAbort) in StartCore.il:line IL_03B3 mvid
> 4421
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object
> s) in ExecutionContextCallback.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in
> RunInternal.il:line IL_0040 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread
> threadPoolThread) in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or
> MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext()
> in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid
> 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox
> box, Boolean allowInlining) in RunOrScheduleAction.il:line IL_003B
> mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject) in RunContinuations.il:line IL_0065 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean userDelegateExecute) in FinishSlow.il:line IL_0003 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject) in TrySetException.il:line IL_0022 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetException(Exception
> exception, Task1& taskField) in SetException.il:line IL_0025 mvid 2BEF
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.TestRunnerRunStrategy.Run(IUnitTestRun
> run) in Run.il:line IL_013D mvid 4421
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object
> s) in ExecutionContextCallback.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in
> RunInternal.il:line IL_0040 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread
> threadPoolThread) in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or
> MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext()
> in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid
> 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox
> box, Boolean allowInlining) in RunOrScheduleAction.il:line IL_003B
> mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject) in RunContinuations.il:line IL_0065 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean userDelegateExecute) in FinishSlow.il:line IL_0003 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject) in TrySetException.il:line IL_0022 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetException(Exception
> exception, Task1& taskField) in SetException.il:line IL_0025 mvid 2BEF
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.TestRunnerRunStrategy.StartTestRunner(IUnitTestRun
> run, ITestRunnerAdditionalStartupOptions environmentSpecifier,
> CancellationToken cancelCt, CancellationToken abortCt) in
> StartTestRunner.il:line IL_008F mvid 4421
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object
> s) in ExecutionContextCallback.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in
> RunInternal.il:line IL_0040 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread
> threadPoolThread) in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or
> MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext()
> in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid
> 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox
> box, Boolean allowInlining) in RunOrScheduleAction.il:line IL_003B
> mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject) in RunContinuations.il:line IL_0065 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean userDelegateExecute) in FinishSlow.il:line IL_0003 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject) in TrySetException.il:line IL_0022 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetException(Exception
> exception, Task1& taskField) in SetException.il:line IL_0025 mvid 2BEF
> at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.Execution.TestRunner.TestRunnerAgentManager.GetExecutionAgent(ITestRunnerExecutionContext
> context, CancellationToken ct) in GetExecutionAgent.il:line IL_0083
> mvid 4421
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object
> s) in ExecutionContextCallback.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in
> RunInternal.il:line IL_0040 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread
> threadPoolThread) in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or
> MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext()
> in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid
> 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox
> box, Boolean allowInlining) in RunOrScheduleAction.il:line IL_003B
> mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject) in RunContinuations.il:line IL_0065 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean userDelegateExecute) in FinishSlow.il:line IL_0003 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject) in TrySetException.il:line IL_0022 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetException(Exception
> exception, Task1& taskField) in SetException.il:line IL_0025 mvid 2BEF
> at JetBrains.dotCover.Ide.Core.UnitTesting.Model.PreloadedTestRunners.PreloadedTestRunnerAgentPool.Allocate(ITestRunnerContext
> context, CancellationToken ct) in Allocate.il:line IL_03CA mvid 168E
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object
> s) in ExecutionContextCallback.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in
> RunInternal.il:line IL_0040 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread
> threadPoolThread) in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or
> MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext()
> in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid
> 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox
> box, Boolean allowInlining) in RunOrScheduleAction.il:line IL_003B
> mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject) in RunContinuations.il:line IL_0065 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean userDelegateExecute) in FinishSlow.il:line IL_0003 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject) in TrySetException.il:line IL_0022 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.SetException(Exception
> exception, Task1& taskField) in SetException.il:line IL_0025 mvid 2BEF
> at JetBrains.dotCover.Ide.Core.UnitTesting.Model.PreloadedTestRunners.PreloadedTestRunnerAgentPool.StartTestRunnerAgentFromNewThread(ITestRunnerContext
> context, CancellationToken ct) in
> StartTestRunnerAgentFromNewThread.il:line IL_00EC mvid 168E
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object
> s) in ExecutionContextCallback.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in
> RunInternal.il:line IL_0040 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext(Thread
> threadPoolThread) in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or
> MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid 2BEF
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1.AsyncStateMachineBox1.MoveNext()
> in MoveNext.il:line IL_0000 mvid 2BEF or MoveNext.il:line IL_003F mvid
> 2BEF
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunForThreadPoolUnsafe[TState](ExecutionContext
> executionContext, Action1 callback, TState& state) in
> RunForThreadPoolUnsafe.il:line IL_001A mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback1.Execute() in Execute.il:line IL_0014 mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() in Dispatch.il:line IL_013F mvid 2BEF
> at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
> in WorkerThreadStart.il:line IL_0067 mvid 2BEF
>
> Last launch log file:
> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Rider2023.1\log\UnitTestLogs\Sessions\2023-07-03-10-16-19-382___0f4fe3ea-45d8-4622-8800-c26dc1705d21.log

Comment: Only when running code coverage or does the normal test runner also crash when running the test?

Comment: only on code coverage, the unit tests are working fine

Comment: Seems to be a long-running task that triggers an exception... I'd recommend creating a ticket [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=97145)